# Bounding-box suddenly way too wide & off-center

Tags: adobe-illustrator, symbols

I've been working in an illustrator file for some time now, but today, all of a sudden, all instances of a symbol I've made are 16k pixels wide (img below).

The objects don't appear that large, but when I click them, the bounding box extends far off-screen to the left and right.

What could cause this? I was editing a symbol when it started happening, but I didn't do anything differently than I've done 100 times before.

[image: animated gif of symptoms i'm describing]

(edit: forgot to include this behavior)
When switching to outline mode, there are two long horizontal lines I can't explain. They aren't guides, and they aren't selectable (all objects are unlocked).

[image]

ETA again: I tried copying into new file, no change. In case anyone's curious, I've uploaded the file in question to Google Drive. Well, it's 2 files [(1)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5-xZWo0P5NWYWg4eDFpcGh1RFU/view?usp=sharing), [(2)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5-xZWo0P5NWV0lscS1NM3p2ZWc/view?usp=sharing):

1. The one tagged [fresh-file] is a new file w/ the objects-in-question copied/pasted in.
2. The other file is the original file, just with extraneous (and problem-free) objects deleted

Illustrator 2015.3.0, Win10

Comment: See what happens if you disable the GPU preview. Shortcut should be `Cmd+E`or `Ctrl+ E`.

Comment: thanks joonas. switched to CPU preview and disabled GPU in prefs, restarted Illustrator.  resulted in no change :\

Comment: Try copying all the content into a new file and see if it shows it there? Not sure I've seen/heard of this in any adobe programs.

Comment: yeah, i feel pretty special to have an issue for which there's not a good deal of literature :)  tried moving to new file, no luck. uploaded .ai files if anyone's interested in taking a look (see OP)

Comment: Scratchin my head here. Perhaps you can ungroup the tile, open the funky box in isolation mode (double click it) and copy out the content from there. At least at that point you have clean shapes/text etc.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a symbol working fine but after resizing it even a bit the bounding box disappears. After un-groupping the whole thing I'm working with I can find it several centimeters away from the symbol. The symbol is totally out of the bounding box. The symbol can't be touched or moved anymore. Re-sizing the bounding box as suggested in the answer is not working. https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0IXG.png

Comment: What I did was start deleting big groups of stuff to trace down the offending object until I found it. What was annoying was that the object was causing bounding box issues even though it was hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After saw your file I figured it out:

There is a huge guide inside the Symbol.

Edit the symbols and clear the guides.

Image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

<sub>(I did not examine your file. Random downloads from unknown sources aren't really great.)</sub>

I think this is a **bug** in symbols.

I have a particular symbol that does this as well.

The only solution I've found is to double-click the offending symbol in the Symbol Panel, to enter symbol editing mode, then exit symbol editing mode -- BAM it's fixed.

I've been unable to determine what causes this bug. As I've posted, I have a document with about 30 symbols... only one of them acts this way every time I open the file or copy the symbol to another file and it's not due to any superfluous artwork or guide.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Clear Guides' mentioned did not work for me, but when I clicked release guides, it released the super long guide so I could delete it. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with an object - not a symbol - with a gradient applied to it. (Bounding box 5 pixels wider than the object on each side.) Replacing the gradient with a solid colour "fixed" the problem and I could at least learn how big the object was before doing a lot of resizing to export a precisely cropped vector. I honestly hope this is not the best solution but I couldn't find any other.

Answer (score -1):

As this is one of the first search results for this problem...

Go to *Object* → *Transform* → *Reset Bounding Box*

Comment: Doesn't do anything in my case.